# How to add multiple conditions to my IF?

Tags: jquery

How to add multiple conditions to my IF ?
I tryed something like this:

```
$('#ok').click(function(){
        if($('#accept-check:checked').length == 1 && #owner.length > 4 && #number.length == 8 ){
            $('#open-box').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#open-box').attr('onclick','javascript:yourFunctionName();');
        }
        else{
            $('#open-box').removeAttr('onclick');
            $('#open-box').attr('disabled','disabled');

    }
    });
```

Comment: The second line is the error

Answer (score 0):

```
var acceptCheckLength=$('#accept-check:checked').length;
var numberCheckLength=$('#number').length;
var ownerLength=$('#owner').length;
```

and use if condition like this

```
if(acceptCheckLength == 1 && ownerLength> 4 && numberCheckLength == 8 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not written the conditions correctly.try this:

```
 if($('#accept-check:checked').length == 1 && $('#owner').length > 4 && $('#number').length == 8 ){
//do stuff here
}
```